# Verilog code to find remainder

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I had written Verilog code in order to find remainder when we divide two numbers. But I face one problem. I have `q` (dividend) and `m` (divisor), `rem` is remainder. My algorithm is:

```
if(q>m)
  q=q-m 
otherwise 
  rem=q
```

I wrote this Verilog code, but `if`-statement runs for once. In next clock cycle it takes value of `p=q`, which I don't want. I want my value in `p` comes as `p=p-m`.

My code is:

```
module div(q,clk,rem,p,count);

  parameter m=13'd840;
  input [12:0] q;
  input clk;
  output reg [12:0] rem;
  output reg [3:0] count;
  output reg [12:0] p;
  initial
    begin
      count=4'b0;
      //+ rem=9'b0;
      //p=13'b0;
    end

  always@(posedge clk)
    begin
      p=q;
      if (p>m)
      begin
        p=p-m;
        count=count+1;
        rem=p;
      end else 
        rem=9'b0;
    end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Please show your testbench. It seems to me that you should get `X`-output with code written the way you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. It should be something like this

```
while(q>=m)
  q=q-m 
rem=q
```

Then, your Verilog module is something like this:

```
module div #(parameter m=13'd840) (
  input wire clk,
  input wire [12:0] q,
  input wire load,
  output reg [12:0] rem,
  output reg finish
  );

  reg [12:0] p;

  always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (load) begin
      finish <= 1'b0;
      p <= m;
    end
    else if (p>=q)
      p <= p - q;
    else begin
      rem <= p;
      finish <= 1'b1;
    end
  end 
endmodule
```

I've added two signals: `load` and `finish`. `load` must be asserted to store a new divisor into `q`. As the time needed for the module to find a remainder is not always the same, the signal `finish` is asserted when there is a valid output in `rem`.

A quick testbench:

```
module tb;
  reg clk,load;
  reg [12:0] q;
  wire [12:0] rem;
  wire finish;

  div uut (clk, q, load, rem, finish);

  initial begin
    clk = 1'b1;
    for (q=1; q<840; q=q+1) begin
      load = 1;
      @(posedge clk); // allow settle load
      load = 0;
      @(posedge finish); // wait until finish is asserted
      @(posedge clk); // allow settle rem
      if (rem!=840%q) begin  // assert rem
        $display ("840 %% %d = %d , %d\n", q, rem, 840%q);        
        $finish;
      end
    end
    $display ("PASSED\n");
  end

  always begin
    clk = #5 ~clk;
  end
endmodule
```